# Me sale este error al usar un diccionario para llamar funciones

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones

Lo que quiero hacer es que en función de un número que ponga el usuario el programa abra una carpeta, el navegador, o se cierre mediante un diccionario en el que cada número hace una función. El problema es que me devuelve un `None` en todos los casos y no el `return` ni la función.

Al introducir `0` se debería cerrar el programa.

Al introducir `1` se debería abrir un .mp3 predeterminado del Windows 7.

Al introducir `2` solo debería abrir la carpeta de música predeterminada.

Al introducir `3` solo poner `"three"` en pantalla.

Y, por último, al introducir `666` que se abriera el Google Chrome con la URL que puse.

En el caso de poner otro número debería salir `"Invalid num"`:

```
import webbrowser
import subprocess
import sys
opened = True

def  one():

     print("Opening explorer.exe")
     #subprocess.Popen(r'explorer /select,"C:\Users\reciclo"')
     subprocess.call("explorer C:\\Users\\Public\\Music\\Sample 
     Music\Kalimba.mp3", shell=True)
     return "opened"
def zero():

    print("Exit the program")
    opened = False
    return "Exit"
def two():

    subprocess.call("explorer C:\\Users\\Public\\Music\\Sample Music", shell=True)

    return "two"
def three():


     return "three"
def demon():

    demon_url = 'https://piv.pivpiv.dk/'
    chrome_path = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'
    webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(demon_url)
    print("3e")
    return "invoked"
def switch_demo(var):

    switcher = {
                0: zero,
                1: one,
                2: two,
                3: three,

               666: demon,

    }
    var = switcher.get(var, "Invalid num")
while opened:
    if opened == True:
     var = int(input("enter a number between 1 and 9999999999 "))
     print(switch_demo(var)))

    elif opened== False:
     print("Alcarrer")
     sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que yo haría sería algo como esto:

```
opened = True

def one():
    print("Running one")
    return "Opened"


def zero():
    global opened
    print("Exit the program")
    opened = False
    return "Exit"

def two():
    print("Running two")
    return "two"


def three():
    print("Running three")
    return "three"


def demon():
    print("Running demon")
    return "invoked"


def invalid():
    print("Invalid option")
    return "Invalid num"


def switch_demo(var):
    switcher = {
                0: zero,
                1: one,
                2: two,
                3: three,
               666: demon,

    }
    func = switcher.get(var, invalid)
    return func()


while opened:
    var = int(input("enter a number between 1 and 9999999999 "))
    print(switch_demo(var))
```

Algunas cosas:

- Para no complicarme, cada función que he puesto de ejemplo tiene su propio `print()` y retorna un valor (una cadena)
- Dentro de la función `zero()` tienes que indicar que quieres usar la variable de afuera usando `global`, de lo contrario estás definiendo una variable local para esa función y tu bucle nunca terminará

  ```
  global opened
  ```
- Te estaba devolviendo `None` en todos los casos porque lo que estás haciendo es ejecutar el resultado de la función `switch_demo(var)` que no devuelve nada. Lo que tienes que hacer es simplemente retornar el resultado de ejecutar la función seleccionada:

  ```
  return func()
  ```
- Dentro de tu `while` no es necesario validar que `opened` sea falso ya que de eso se encarga la condición inicial del bucle:

  ```
  while opened: # Mientras que opened sea verdadero
  ```
- Creé la función `invalid` que sirve como función cuando el número ingresado es inálido. De esta forma se puede ejecutar su resultado como las demás funciones

Mis funciones solo imprimen y retornan un valor pero el resultado de ejecutar ese script se ve más o menos así:

```
$ python3 switcher.py 
enter a number between 1 and 9999999999 1
Running one
Opened
enter a number between 1 and 9999999999 2
Running two
two
enter a number between 1 and 9999999999 3
Running three
three
enter a number between 1 and 9999999999 4
Invalid option
Invalid num
enter a number between 1 and 9999999999 5
Invalid option
Invalid num
enter a number between 1 and 9999999999 666
Running demon
invoked
enter a number between 1 and 9999999999 454564654
Invalid option
Invalid num
enter a number between 1 and 9999999999 0
Exit the program
Exit
```